Get the length of an array using closure validation
What I am trying to do is to get the length of an array inside closure Laravel validation.
Here is what I have tried:
        'attachment' => 'max:10',
        'attachment.*' => 'max:10240|mimes:jpeg,jpg,pdf',

        'deletedAttachments' => ['nullable', 'array', 'max:10', function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $fail(count($this->input('attachment')));
        }],

Unfortunately, This did not work and I am getting the following error:

Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString::__toString(): Return value must be of type string, null returned


Where are you running this validation (controller, form request, etc ...)? And please explain what are you exactly trying to do.

as I remember, Laravel validation should give the data type first, maybe you could try:
[
'attachment' => 'array|max:10',
'attachment.*' => 'file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,pdf|max:10240',
//...other codes
]


The issue was from the client side. Your answer is useful though. Thank  you.
